# Dba related Query in ASE 16

Tags: sap-ase

Recently we have observed Update Statistics are getting failed for huge tables
in ASE 16. But we don't find enough information regarding failure in SID.Log.
Request to assist me on this.

Environment AIX7.1/SYBASE ASE16/ECC 6.0 EHP7

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to insufficient space in the procedure cache. if so, there will be a mention of error 701 in the ASE errorlog file (run SELECT @@ERRORLOG to find its location)

Comment: hi rob,thanks for your reply aleardy we have check the SID.log